# XSLT - Root element not set

Tags: xml, xslt

Getting a Root element not set error on my XSLT.

XML Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customer count="1">
  <Record id="123">
    <Data id="123-00">John Smith</Data>
  </Record>
   <Record id="456">
    <Data id="123-00">Mark Doe</Data>
  </Record>
 </Customer>
```

Desired Output:

```
<Customer>
    <Record>
        <Name>John Smith<Name>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Name>Mark Doe</Name>
    </Record>
</Customer>
```

What I had so far:

```
<xsl:template match="/Customer/Record">
    <xsl:for-each select="Data">
    <Customer>
        <Record>        
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="@id='123-00'"/></Name>
        </Record>
    </Customer>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I tried without the for loop code and use `template match="/"` with `value-of select="Customer/Record/Name[@id='123-00']"` and it works. But I know it's not the best way to code it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to transform `Data` elements to `Name` elements and drop any attributes then use

```
<xsl:template match="Data">
  <Name>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </Name>
</xsl:template>
```

For the other elements you seem to want to copy them without their attributes so adding a template

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

suffices: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKxi

Comment: When I tried template match ="Data", I'm still getting a root element not set error. I used template match="/Customer" then <xsl:for-each select="Record">.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code produce the output you want, you need to:

1. Make your template match `Customer` instead of `Record`;
2. Move the `Customer` element **outside** the `xsl:for-each` instruction;
3. Get the actual value of the `Data` node (what you have now is only a Boolean test):

```
<xsl:template match="/Customer">
    <Customer>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record">
            <Record>        
                <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Data[@id='123-00']"/>
                </Name>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Customer>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I got confused on where to start the for loop.